# How to parse argument with args4j in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, args4j

I need to parse info from command line, so  I choose args4j library. Format of command line: ls [-l] [-h] [-r] [-o output.file] directory_or_file.

I've tried to create options and then parse. When I get only "-ls", output is correct, but when I get "-ls -l"(more than 1 argument) the program does not stop and I can enter on the command line until I forcibly stop the program. 
I will be grateful for any help!

```
public class Settings {
    @Option(name = "-ls", usage = "Init command")
    var command  = false
    @Option(name = "-l", usage = "Long flag")
    var longFlag  = false
    @Option(name = "-h")
    var humanReadable = false
    @Option(name = "-r")
    var reversed = false

}
fun main() {
    val settings = Settings()
    val parser = CmdLineParser(settings)
    var args = mutableListOf<String>()
    val input = readLine()
    parser.parseArgument(input)
    print("${settings.command} ${settings.longFlag}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not exactly answer your question but if your platform allows, you may try adding parameters as environment variables. It is usually more convenient to define them in the `Makefile` or `Dockerfile` if you're working with microservices. Or you can add them in front of the app command to push them into the app as environment variables. The syntax is:

```
FOO=bar appcommand
```

With kotlin, you can use the following example to read environment variables:

```
System.getenv("FOO")
```

will return "bar".